# Rotation matrix is scaling

Tags: java, opengl, matrix

I am using OpenGL 3.2 in Java via LWJGL, and have discovered that using glRotate is no longer possible. So, I coded up some rotation matrices to handle rotating. The only problem is that they are scaling the objects when they are rotated, and I can't figure out why.

My matrix creator:

```
Matrix4f rmat = new Matrix4f(); // identity
float c = (float) Math.cos(theta);
float s = (float) Math.sin(theta);
rmat.m00 = c;
rmat.m11 = c;
rmat.m10 = s;
rmat.m01 = -s;
```

The result is a scaled image, I am not sure how much. The difference is noticeable in this picture: [image: RotScaled]

Does anyone know why this is going on or how to fix it?

NB: This is part of a very large internal library, I am not sure how much could be extracted into an example. Feel free to run the RotationTest class that produced the image from [here](https://github.com/TechShroom/EmergencyLanding). Sorry that there isn't a jar, but the library doesn't play nice with jars right now.

Comment: I don't see any scaling in your rotated image. Can you add an image that you would expect as output?

Comment: Interesting. Rotating it in an image program produces the same result. However, I would expect that rotations don't lower the quality of the image as this seems to do. Is this impossible to do?

Comment: If your triangles are in a texture make sure to turn on linear filtering. In general, quality is very subjective for rotation. You can play with the concept by rotating one piece of graph paper on top of another. One is source texels, the other destination pixels. Do you pick the closest one? Make sure all source texels get a spot? Or blend by how much area they take up?

Comment: that the diagonal of the square is ~1.4 times larger than the sides is completely normal and a direct result of the Pythagorean formula

Comment: @ratchet Yes, but is there any way to make it close to 1 times larger? Is it possible to scale it down by exactly that much?

Comment: Yes, divide both c and s by `Math.sqrt(2)`. But that is an area reducing operation, applying this scaled rotation twice will result in a square that is only half as big (in length) as the original.

Comment: Hmm, while using red squares to replace the texture, it seems okay to me. I think that the image quality loss is probably what's making it seem scaled.